# Saving changed serialized values (Unity Editor C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization, editor, inspector

I've written a custom GUI for automation in unity as shown below

```
 [CustomEditor(typeof(myObject ))]
 //[CanEditMultipleObjects]
 public class myObjectInspectorGUI : Editor
 {
     public override void OnInspectorGUI()
     {
         //serializedObject.Update();

         DrawDefaultInspector();

         myObject target= (myObject )target;
         if (GUILayout.Button("Add a new item to list"))
         {
             target.addItemToMyStructArray();
        
         }

         //serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
     }
 }
```

And the original object is this:

```
public class myObject : MonoBehaviour
{
   [SerializeField] private myStruct[] myStructArray;

   [System.Serializable]
   public struct myStruct
   {
       [SerializeField] public int value1;
       [SerializeField] public float value2;
   }

public void addItemToMyStructArray()
{
    myStruct[] newArray= new myStruct[myStructArray.Length + 1];
    for(int i=0;i< myStructArray.Length; i++)
    {
        newArray[i] = myStructArray[i];
    }

    myStruct tempItem;
    tempItem.value1= 12;
    tempItem.value2= 15.5f;

    newArray[myStructArray.Length] = tempItem;
    myStructArray= newArray;

   }
}
```

and the button works fine and adds the items to the array in the inspector but the problem is that **the changes will not save and Serialize !! and when I hit play the changes are gone :(**

I also tried adding the commented codes int the first script but no luck

what am I doing wrong??

Comment: This sounds familiar ;) See here: [Custom inspector reverting values back to previous values on Play in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66588861/custom-inspector-reverting-values-back-to-previous-values-on-play-in-unity/66589836#66589836)   in short: Before `target.addItemToMyStructArray();` add `Undo.RecordObject(myObject, "AddItem");`

Comment: That's not entirely true: It works with custom Structs but you will have to either get sub properties via `serializedProperty.FindPropertyRelative("name");` or build a custom property drawer

Comment: thanks for your fast reply. I tried your code and it could only save the array size but still keeping the default values in structs which is 0. I also read the link you attached and tried using SerializedProperty but it was not functional because it only works with default data types and not a struct in my case.

Comment: okay i try this one . thanks again.

Comment: YES the FindPropertyRelative("variable name") worked perfectly. thanks a lot ^0^